# Jquery change <p> text programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

EDIT: The solution was to add this to the profile page instead of the gender page.

```
$('#profile').live( 'pageinit',function(event){
$('p#pTest').text(localStorage.getItem('gender'));
```

});

I have a paragraph with som text in a listview that I want to change programatically from another page after clikcing save.

EDIT: This is my listview in profile.html. When you click on the item you get to another page where you can save your gender. I want to change the paragraph in this listview to the gender that was changed from the other page.

```
<ul data-role="listview"   >
    <li><a href="gender.html">
        <img src="images/gender2.jpg" />
        <h3>Gender</h3>
        <p id="pTest">Male</p>
    </a></li> </ul>
```

The gender html page is just basic stuff with two radio buttons and a save button. 
Here is my javascript code(in a seperate file):

```
$('#gender').live('pageinit', function(event) {

    var gender = localStorage.getItem('gender');
    var boolMale = true;
    if (gender == "female") boolMale = false;
    $('#radio-choice-male').attr("checked",boolMale).checkboxradio("refresh");
    $('#radio-choice-female').attr("checked",!boolMale).checkboxradio("refresh");

    $('#saveGenderButton').click(function() {
        if ($('#radio-choice-male').is(':checked'))
            localStorage.setItem('gender', "male");
        else localStorage.setItem('gender', "female");

        $('#pTest').html('test'); //does not work
         //$('p#pTest').text('test'); //does not work
         //$('#pTest').text('test'); //does not work
        $.mobile.changePage("profile.html");
    });
});
```

I have tried this with javascript: `$('p#pTest').text('test');`

The text does not change however. (I know that the save button works). Is this possible?

Comment: Your code should work the way it is. What do you mean by "from another page"?

Comment: What do you mean with "change programatically from another page after clicking save"?  Can we see some code? Both HTML and JS?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Try the following, note that when the user refreshes the page, the value is "Male" again, data should be stored on a database.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
     $('#pTest').text('test')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="pTest">Male</p>
<button>change</button>
```

Comment: I have tried this, just with javascript in seperate file. See my edit

Comment: After yoir comment about database I figured it out. I just had to add this to the profile page instead of the gender page.$('#profile').live( 'pageinit',function(event){
    $('p#pTest').text(localStorage.getItem('gender'));

});

Comment: Does this have an issue in iOS safari? I am trying to change the text of a button on its click 
$('#testbtn').click(function(){
     $(''#testbtn').text('test')
}); 
where 'testbtn' is the id of the button. This works fine in all browsers, mobile and web, but doesn't change the text in iOS safari.

Answer (score 0):

"saving" is something wholly different from changing paragraph content with jquery.

If you need to save changes you will have to write them to your server somehow (likely form submission along with all the security and input sanitizing that entails). If you have information that is saved on the server then you are no longer changing the content of a paragraph, you are drawing a paragraph with dynamic content (either from a database or a file which your server altered when you did the "saving").

Judging by your question, this is a topic on which you will have to do MUCH more research.

Input page (input.html):

```
<form action="/saveMyParagraph.php">
    <input name="pContent" type="text"></input>
</form>
```

Saving page (saveMyParagraph.php) and Ouput page (output.php):

[Inserting Data Into a MySQL Database using PHP](http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php#.T6gDG-htbjs)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have the click event wrapped around a custom event name "pageinit", are you sure you're triggered the event before you click the button?

something like this:

```
$("#gender").trigger("pageinit");
```