# Show Auto complete responce multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

[image]

i am able to append the image and i want to append student id in hallticket number how can i do that.?
This my html:

```
<td><b>Hallticket:</b>S<div><p class="hallticketNumber">***studentid has to come here***</p>J'+jobID+'</div></td>
<td><div><img class="participantphoto" src=""/><input class="searchStudent" type="text" autocomplete="off"><input class="studentId" type="hidden" name="gdtest['+studentCount+'][studentId]"></div></td>
```

this what i have tried:

```
$(this).closest('div').find(".studentId").attr("value",ui.item.student_pid);//working
$(this).closest('div').find(".participantphoto").attr("src",ui.item.profile_pic);//working
$(this).closest('div').find(".hallticketNumber").attr("label",ui.item.student_pid); //Notworking
```

> the error is in last line near `.attr("label",ui.item.student_pid);`

Answer (score 2):

Use [**text()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486010/jquery-change-p-text-programatically) to change content of paragraph dynamically.

```
$(".hallticketNumber").text(ui.item.student_pid);
```

Comment: is there only one paragraph <p> tag with class hallticketNumber ?

Comment: `$(this).closest('div')` is not working for `<p class="hallticketNumber"> `becuase its a different div then referenced for `<img class="participantphoto" src=""/>` and `<input class="searchStudent" .. >`. Try above solution if there is only one p tag with class hallticketNumber

Comment: i am having proble  all the <p> are changing if i change one, so neeed the `closet one` line.. @mhasan